# What is difference between is_unique column and is_unique_constraint columns in sys.indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

We have two columns `is_unique` and `is_unique_constraint` for unique constraints in `sys.indexes` and I want to clarify few concepts based on these two columns

1. Create statement for both types of indexes are same except `fill factor` property value or do I missing something?
2. If statement 1 is true then why we have two columns in sys.indexes for unique constraint?
3. When `is_unique=1 is_unique_constraint =0` and then drop statement for index is
   `DROP INDEX [index name] ON [dbo].[TableName] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )`

   And when `is_unique=1 is_unique_constraint =1` and then drop statement for index is
   `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [IndexName]`

   Why is that so?
4. Where we use unique index and where unique constraint, what is best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fact is that there is no practical difference between a unique constraint and a unique index.

1. Querying `sys.objects`, you will find unique constraint is listed as a constraint object and its related index can be found while querying `sys.indexes`, where it is marked `is_unique = 1` as well as `is_unique_constraint = 1`. On other hand, for a unique indexes `is_unique_constraint` value will be zero (0).
2. While creating unique constraint you can use Fill Factor option as compare to unique index where you have more options like `FILLFACTOR, PAD_INDEX, IGNORE_DUP_KEY, DROP_EXISTING, and STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE`.
3. Unique constraint is maintained through a unique index
4. Just like Default and Primary Key, a unique constraint can't be disabled using NOCHECK syntax
5. To delete a unique index with `is_unique_constraint = 1`, it is must to delete it through DROP CONSTRAINT syntax instead of DROP INDEX because such index is associated with a unique constraint (object), so one must drop CONSTRAINT and index will be dropped automatically.

As **best practice**, If uniqueness is required then always apply unique constraint, instead of creating only unique index. This way you can't drop a unique index accidentally.Also this way you can document all applied constraints easily.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @@aasim so unique constraint is better than just creating unique index?

Comment: Personally I prefer unique constraint when uniqueness is required.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to aasims' answer, the only major difference here being a `Unique Index` is **not** a database object. Whereas a `unique Constraint` is an object.

However other than that there are no other major differences:

- They both achieve the same performance
- They both achieve the same end goal.

**EDIT:**

Why would you use Unique Index vs Constraint, what's the best practice?

There isn't a one size fits all best practice here. For one main reason (at least). A Unique Constraint only allows for one null value in the column. However, you can create a Unique Index without including the `null` values:

```
Create unique Index MyUniqueIndex on Contacts (ContactId) where Email is not null
```

This would create the index but **ONLY** where the values on the Email column aren't null.

Comment: Actually my curiosity is, if both have same goals, same performance then why we create unique index? So we should always be recommended to use unique constraint, are we?

Comment: Edited my answer